# Scroll to Bottom of Page Not Working (Python Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Why doesn't `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")` work on [this apple music playlist](https://music.apple.com/ca/playlist/christmas-songs/pl.3597190614364be9a39a6011cfdfd7f3)? That line of code works fine on every other website I visit.

I tried doing `action.send_keys_to_element(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html'), Keys.END)` to no avail.

How else could I scroll to the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use any interactable node like below:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'play-button').send_keys(Keys.END)
```